# Safety on communications cable that has 220v

Tags: safety, power

As you know there are bias tee adapters that can mix power and radio signals.
Lets say that the power is actually 220v ac. I want to put in front of the bias tee a resistor/fuse that should blow up before somebody gets electrified to death. Can somebody suggest how to calculate that ? What is the current or wattage when a person gets electrified so the fuse can blow and I can get the proper rating?
Person seems to have ~1000 ohms resistance by watching the mythbuster tests if that helps.
No more than 7 watts are needed for the communications cable and latter equipment to work.

Comment: Would you update your Q to indicate what country you're in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Is this an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info)?

FWIW this seems like an [example of the XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info), where you're asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem. Perhaps you would consider backing up and sharing what you're trying to accomplish with this solution?

## That's not what a bias tee does

You'll be mixing two AC signals on the line, which is not what a typical bias tee is engineered to do... I really think you'll be better off reframing your question with what you're attempting to accomplish, and why. If you share what problem your proposed solution is *indended* to solve, we may be able to suggest something you find more appropriate.

## High current 220v power is deadly

For AC power, you should just have an electrician spec out an appropriate 220v GFCI/AFI breaker at the appropriate ampacity. Your questions indicate you do not have sufficient awareness of power safety requirements to attempt to DIY this. please Please PLEASE work with a professional.

Comment: ohhh good point about bias-Tees typically being DC blocks, and in the ham context, might really not have all too much bandwidth between "frequency blocked" and "Frequency let through", even if they *could* stand the voltage. Yeah! You'd be feeding whatever of these 50 or 60 Hz passes through the blocking capacitor. And since the amplitude of the grid voltage is so many orders of magnitude higher than the signal in a typical application of bias-Tees (namely, LNAs), you'd totally damage whatever circuitry you have there.

Answer (score 5):

A fuse doesn't care about watts delivered. It limits current, and nothing else. So there is nothing to calculate:

5 mA through the heart can be fatal, and at 220 V, you already have a significant contact risk.

**BUT**

1. the fact that you're even asking this strongly suggests you shouldn't be doing this. I will not deviate from this opinion. Do not harm yourself or others. This is a bad idea for technical and for human safety reasons.
2. A fuse is **never** sufficient as single barrier to death. That is actually an important principle. A fuse can be enough to protect equipment from overcurrents and can consequently also make humans safer (e.g. by avoiding fires started by shorted cables), but it is never what you use to make a system safe enough to handle. If you have a system of any sort that is not sufficiently isolated from dangerous voltage sources (like what you propose), you must make it untouchable, add residual current protection or have interlocks that disable supply when someone might be close enough to touch it. A bias-Tee is not a sufficient isolation, so this applies to amplifiers, radios, antennas, filters, tuners and whatever you connect to the same conductor.
3. I don't see any use case for this. By superimposing such a voltage to the RF field carried by whatever wave guide you're thinking of (probably coax cable), you need to derate the maximum electrical field strength that the cable can sustain by the power voltage. Two options, essentially: either the specified RF field strength is high compared to what your 220V potential difference would contribute, then you have expensive coax for high powers, and the device at the end that you power through your bias-Tee will draw so much current that you curse your decision to use the coax to transport basically 0 Hz power, because that heats up your expensive cable and is less efficient than running cheap power cabling in parallel (coax is **not** a good 50/60 Hz cable), or, you're actually supplying a low-power device like an LNA and ask about high voltages because you want to run power for a long distance, and ohmic losses are baking that hard. In that case, you curse your decision to use long coax to transport power, because you now have to use more expensive coax to sustain the high field strength.

Unless you **really** know why you're doing this, and that doesn't seem to be the case, considering your wattage/fuse confusion, I'll say that you're proposing an expensive but dangerous solution to an easy problem that can just be solved with a parallel run of classical power cable.